# is there any safe application for windows 7 that scans hardwares and find adequate drivers for them?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically Find Driver Updates?](https://superuser.com/questions/282382/automatically-find-driver-updates)

i'm a owner of an hp `G32-301TX` bought in `Singapore`, and for an unknown reason it came with a windows 7 home premium.I've switch to windows7 ultimate and deleted the backup drive.i've downloaded all required (i believe) but it seems like i've not found drivers for keyboard shortcut buttons like `mute` or `volume +` `volume -` .

So i'm wondering if there is a `safe` application that could find missing drivers or find the right drivers for my machine.

thanks for reading...

Comment: Install HPSA, see if it finds any more....http://h18021.www1.hp.com/helpandsupport/HPSA.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no application that I know of that is HP-specific.

What you are looking for in this case is not a driver, but an application, so what you asked for would not work anyway.

Specifically I think this is probably under "Software solutions>HP Quick Launch Software", which is described as "This package contains the HP Quick Launch Software, which enables special function keys on supported notebook models to be programmed."

Pick 32-bit or 64-bit here, then navigate to Software solutions>HP Quick Launch Software.

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=5064635&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&prodClassId=-1&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=4346225

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Driver Detective](http://www.driverdetective.org.uk/) before and it seems to be pretty good - for most drivers, it can auto-install. For others it can't automate, it gives detailed instructions, download URLs, etc.

It's worth noting, however, that **you need to pay for full functionality**. If I remember correctly, it will scan and identify drivers free but you have to pay to see what it's found. This should at least let you test if it can find the driver before paying.

There may be better (free) alternatives but I don't know of any